# Finish animation of swipe to delete on recyclerView first before deleting on Frestore

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I have swipe to delete on my recycler view, and I have this code on my adapter's deleteItem:

```
 public void deleteItem(int position) {
    moveFirestoreDocument(from, movedTo);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

The code works, but it's just really slow. When swiping, recyclerView will wait for Firestore's entry to disappear from the list before the read bar (onSwipe) disappear.

I plan to incorporate an undo feature later, but for now, how do I get recycler view to work smoothly without waiting for Firestore's deletion?

Comment: I also tried to get offline  (mFirestore.disableNetwork();) to do the deletion to hopefully use the offline cache to reduce latency, but it does not work as well too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 public void deleteItem(int position) {
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    moveFirestoreDocument(from, movedTo);
 }
```